# how we can run multiple queries on Firebase/firestore to get filtered data in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

how we can run multiple queries on  **Firebase**/ firestore to get filtered data in **flutter** or any other possible solution? there is a picture storing dummy data in goal and title and wanna users according to the goals and titles **filters**.
[image: filter UI]

[image: firebsae data]

Answer (score 1):

Where() is a function provided by Firebase to query data

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('yourCollectionName').where('field1', isEqual:'value1').where('field2', isEqual: 'value2').get();
```

you can read more about it in the querying section at https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your Firestore database it is clear that you want to filter the documents based on two array fields `goals` and `titles`.

Firestore supports the `arrayContains` filter in the `where` clause by which you can filter data from an array inside Firestore. So you may think of doing something like this -

```
var filter1 = 'Hire Employees';
   var filter2 = 'CEO';
   FirebaseFirestore.instance
       .collection('collectionId')
       .where('goals', arrayContains: filter1)
       .where('titles', arrayContains: filter2)
       .get()
       .then((QuerySnapshot docs) => {
             for (var element in docs.docs) {print(element.data())}
           });
```

But the above will throw an error saying that `You cannot use 'array-contains' filters more than once`. This is because Firestore has a limitation that you can use at most one array-contains clause per query which is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations_2). **So it is not possible to do something like the above.**

I am not very sure of your use case, but as a workaround, you can restructure the database structure by making any one of the array field to a map, something like the following -

[image]

By making the structure like the above you can use multiple `where` clauses with one `arrayContains` filter and one `isEqualTo` filter which will look something like this -

```
   var filter1 = 'Hire Employees';
   var filter2 = 'CEO';
   FirebaseFirestore.instance
       .collection('collectionId')
       .where('goals.$filter1', isEqualTo: true)
       .where('titles', arrayContains: filter2)
       .get()
       .then((QuerySnapshot docs) => {
             for (var element in docs.docs) {print(element.data())}
           });
```

As the idea of allowing multiple `arrayContains` filters is currently not supported, but could be valid, I would recommend you [file a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=530136&template=1192475).